# Sending a DM through a command, to a specific person from a database, discord.js-commando

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I having an issue of sending a DM to a specific person without an author tag, and without a mention of the person. I tried duplicating the mention array:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

class Msgowner extends commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'msgowner',
      group: 'info',
      memberName: 'msgowner',
      description: 'Gives rules on mock or legit duels.',
      examples: ['ladderrules type'],
    });
  }

  async run(message) {
    var user = {
      id: '12345',
      username: 'Bloodmorphed',
      discriminator: '12345',
      avatar: 'd510ca3d384a25b55d5ce7f4c259b2d0',
      bot: false,
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessage: null,
    };
    user.send('Test');
  }
}

module.exports = Msgowner;
```

There is a reason why I need to send DMs this way, but I can't seem to figure out how. (The error it gives now is a unknown function). Also replacing id and discriminator with generic numbers, but they are correct in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this - get the member you're looking for using `message.channel.members.find()` method:

```
async run(message) {
    // get Collection of members in channel
    let members = message.channel.members;

    // find specific member in collection - enter user's id in place of '<id number>'
    let guildMember = members.find('id', '<id number>');

    // send Direct Message to member
    guildMember.send('test message');
}
```

**Edit:** It looks like it's also possible to find users outside the current channel by doing something like this:

```
async run(message) {
    // get client from message's channel
    let client = message.channel.client;

    // fetch user via given user id
    let user = client.fetchUser('<id number>')
    .then(user => {
        // once promise returns with user, send user a DM
        user.send('Test message'); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, `message.channel.members` would only pull a list of people in a channel of the server right? So what would I do if I wanted the whole scope of the server, and not just a channel? Also I haven't actually tested this yet, I'm hard pressed on time ATM.

Comment: Okay, this does work. Thank you very much! But still curious about pull members from the whole "guild", unless `.channel` actually does that.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the upvote. `.channel` just references the exact channel where the message (from the params) came from, and `.members` gets a `Collection` of all of the GuildMembers in that channel. So if you're trying to send a direct message to someone outside the channel, you may have to try something else

Comment: @William - See my updated answer. I think this new method actually allows you to search for users outside of a given channel - hopefully any user on the server.

Comment: Man the infrastructure is so confusing to get a handle on starting out. This worked like a charm, thank you VERY much! Now, way later and a different bot, will need to find out a way to send DMs cross server :O. But thats another day, thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found my answer:

```
  async run(message) {
    var user = {
      id: '12345,
      username: 'Bloodmorphed',
      discriminator: '12345',
      avatar: 'd510ca3d384a25b55d5ce7f4c259b2d0',
      bot: false,
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessage: null,
    };
    console.log(user);
    message.member.user.send('Test');
  }
}

module.exports = Msgowner;
```

EDIT: This was NOT the answer, still looking for one.

Comment: Okay, so I have figured out, all you need is the ID. Nothing else is needed. can also removed the single qutoes and the whole array and just have it as `user = 12345;` which is nice.

Comment: You don't need the `var user = {...}` - in your code, this variable isn't being used

Comment: I noticed. So I am back to square one. Don't know how to send to specific people.